# Entity framework, what is the purpose of List<> in construtor:

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, frameworks, ef-code-first

```
public class Standard
{
    public Standard()
    {
        Students = new List<Student>();
    }
    public int StandardId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

What is the purpose of construting  `Students = new List<Student>();` above for EF code first?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly don't have to initialize Students in the constructor. There are also other patterns. Note that it's entirely possible to construct an object without the constructor ever running (for example, some serializers work that way), so this may not even work in all cases.

Until you initialize Students, it will be null. If you try `Students.Add(myStudent)` somewhere in your code before any initialization happens, you will get a NullReferenceException.

Another common pattern is to perform a lazy initialization of the Students property, e.g.

```
private List<Student> students;
public List<Student> Students 
{
    get
    {
        if (students == null) students = new List<Student>();
        return students;
    }
    set { students = value; }
}
```

This pattern can be helpful if an object might be constructed without the constructor running, but also has its own set of pitfalls (for example, as written it is not thread safe).

Comment: I see this in EF Models fluent api samples: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx It is like, it is worth something to construct it but can not be sure of what?

Comment: It's a very common pattern and works well in most cases.

Comment: It is obvious that is common. But for what purpose exactly?

Comment: If you don't initialize Students, you cannot add anything to your list. Try commenting out the line `Students = new List<Student>();` and give it a try. Students will be null, so the first time you try to add something to Students (without having initialized it) you will get a NullReferenceException. Effectively, that would be like doing `null.Add(myStudent)`

Comment: But If I agree to initialize later, do I still have to add it to constr.?

Comment: No, you just have to be sure it is initialized before you add anything to it. You could even make that the caller's responsibility, though that's usually not the best option since the code to check whether it is initialized would be repeated many times in your code.

Comment: Thank you. So it is just for safety and against null exceptions that may happen in code. Also against code repatations.

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.